# VBA rename sheet based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I want a VBA code that rename my sheetXXX, where XXX is the value in the cell B5 in “Sheet1” sheet. The macro should work for any value in B5.

I tried the following code:

```
Sub tabname()
    Dim sheetXXX As Worksheet
    XXX.Name = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of using Worksheets("Sheet1") you should use ActiveSheet Propery to know more visit [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the object = to the actual worksheet to be renamed.

```
Sub tabname()
    Dim sheetXXX As Worksheet
    Set sheetXXX = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheetXXX")
    sheetXXX.Name = "Sheet" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Value
End Sub
```

If sheetXXX is meant to be the active worksheet you would do this.

```
Sub tabname()
    Dim sheetXXX As Worksheet
    Set sheetXXX = ActiveWorkbook.Activesheet
    sheetXXX.Name = "Sheet" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you change  `XXX.Name` =  to `sheetXXX.Name =` in the third line?

Comment: It is not the active worksheet, so we have to use ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheetXXX")
But unfortunately, it is not work eihter :/

Comment: if I change XXX.Name = to sheetXXX.Name = in the third line, the sheet will be rename to the value of B5 instead of sheet & the value of B5. For example if B5=2015,  the sheet have to be rename as sheet2015

Comment: See edit to my answer.  You can add the word sheet in front of the value.  = "Sheet" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Value