# VBA Excel autopopulate new sheets based on the cell value for incrementing cells

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to auto-populate new sheets in Excel with their names based on the cell value. However, it won't be the value from one cell but from the list of cells in the row. The name of the first worksheet will be fetched from the 1st cell value, the name of the second worksheet from the 2nd cell value, and so on...
I defined the maximum range of these cells - 20 in the row, but not all of them will have the values. I want the new sheets to be created only from these cells, where value is provided.

[image]

I used the following code:

```
 Sub Namedsheetsadding()
 Dim wsr As Worksheet, wso As Worksheet
 Dim i As Long, xCount As Long
 Dim SheetName As String

 Set wsr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vetro Area Map 1")


 SheetName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Frontsheet").Range("D122:D142")  'including empty cells either, but 
 not creating new sheets for them

 For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
 If InStr(1, Sheets(i).name, "Vetro") > 0 Then xCount = xCount + 1
 Next

 wsr.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wsr.Index - 1 + xCount)
 ActiveSheet.name = "Vetro Area Map " & SheetName & xCount + 1

 End Sub
```

Based on some solutions here:

- [VBA rename sheet based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262000/vba-rename-sheet-based-on-cell-value)
- http://excelexperts.com/vba-code-adding-new-sheet-based-cell-value
- https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-create-new-sheet-based-on-cell-data.740895
- [EXCEL VBA Dynamic Sheet Name according to a cell value - Not working when formula in the cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46666069/excel-vba-dynamic-sheet-name-according-to-a-cell-value-not-working-when-formul)

which apply to one cell only

Possibly this is the reason, why I am getting:

**Error: Type mismatch**

for the following line:

```
  SheetName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Frontsheet").Range("D122:D142")  'including empty cells either, but not creating new sheets for them
```

Is there any chance to make the sheet auto-population with names based on the cell range?

Comment: A multi-cell range value will return an array, you can't store an array in a string type variable, you will need to loop through and get each cell value individually (or store it in an array and loop the array)

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: If you could explain in more detail. There are two workbooks many worksheets. What exactly is being copied where? What is being renamed? `D122:D142` contains 21 cells.

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008, yeah I didn't get that either, I'm not sure it's two workbooks though. Looks like he is looping for an iteration... hence my answer.

Comment: The one worksheet is the "Frontsheet" where the cell values are stored. Another worksheet is "Area Map 1" which is referral for other worksheets which will be populated.

Comment: @MKR sorry, that's not too clear.  I don't know what "FrontSheet" means. Maybe you could explain what you're trying to do. Your code is set to only add one sheet and it's getting an error because you're trying to give it a name of an array of text values in cells `D122:D142`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for,it gets an array from the range, converts it into a 1d array and then makes the sheets.

```
 Sub Namedsheetsadding()
 Dim wsr As Worksheet, wso As Worksheet
 Dim i As Long, xCount As Long
 Dim SheetNames As Variant   'This needs to be variant
 Dim sheetname As Variant
 Dim newsheet As Worksheet
 Dim lr As Long
 
 Set wsr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vetro Area Map 1")

 lr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Frontsheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row 'Get last row
 SheetNames = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Frontsheet").Range("D122:D" & lr)  'including empty cells either, but not creating new sheets for them
 SheetNames = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(SheetNames, , 1)) 'Converts the 2d array into a 1d array
 For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    If InStr(1, Sheets(i).Name, "Vetro") > 0 Then xCount = xCount + 1
 Next

 For Each sheetname In SheetNames
    wsr.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wsr.Index - 1 + xCount)
    Set newsheet = Sheets(wsr.Index + xCount)
    newsheet.Name = "Vetro Area Map " & sheetname
    xCount = xCount + 1 'Preserve order of sheets from range
 Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: Nice answer. An array is the way to go, I just didn't understand what OP was doing after the first loop. `Upvoted!`

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question, `YES`, you can make sheets automatically named, but you'll need to handle your rules better. You're getting an error because you're trying to reference an array to a single string. I would recommend learning about arrays ([Paul Kelly](https://www.linkedin.com/in/paul-kelly-kk/) has some [great stuff here](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/)), but there might be other ways to approach your specific issue.

If you're more familiar with Excel than VBA, you should try to make a cell formula rule that populates a *SINGLE* cell that should be the next name of a worksheet. If you can have a cell that will always have the proper name, then you can always have your code reference the same value.

Alternatively, you might want to use the [VBA offset function](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/offset.php), which is pretty easier for newer coders to comprehend.

See below as an example.

```
Sub makeNewWorksheets()
 Dim wsr As Worksheet, wso As Worksheet
 Dim i As Long, xCount As Long
 Dim SheetName As String

 Dim startTingCell As Range
    Set startTingCell = Range("D122")
    
 For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
   If InStr(1, Sheets(i).Name, "Vetro") > 0 Then xCount = xCount + 1
 Next

        'Changes the cell being referenced by xCount
            Set startTingCell = startTingCell.Offset(xCount, 0)
            
        'helps explain what is happening. Delete after you've grasped what's up.
        MsgBox "The cell that will be set to the name is " & startTingCell.Address & _
        "with a value of " & startTingCell.Value
        
        wsr.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wsr.Index - 1 + xCount)
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Vetro Area Map " & startTingCell.Value
        
End Sub
```

Comment: I think we are almost there.
I am getting an error: Object variable or With block variable not set 
wsr.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wsr.Index - 1 + xCount)

Comment: That just means it's got the wrong sheet count. Do you care what order it's in? If not just use `After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)`

Comment: It still throws an error with this line of code

Comment: I am giving you the upvote because I appreciate your effort. I believe it's mostly my fault here, which I will try to sort out. If not today, then later. Thank you.